How to generate several sources in one parenthesis in APA style?
I am trying to generate a citation with multiple sources. Desired result:

Several studies have replicated these results (Brown, 2009; Porter,
2004; Smith, 2015, 2017).

I have tried using ~\cite{brown2009, porter2004, smith2015}. I get an error by using this. Using the package cite \usepackage{cite} will resolve it. However, instead of getting parenthesis, it turned to brackets

Several studies have replicated these results [Brown, 2009; Porter,
2004; Smith, 2015, 2017].

How to properly use it without turning it to brackets?

As always on this site, please provide a full but minimal example others can copy and test. From your question, the only thing we know is that you have used the cite pages. Are you using  natbib? Exactly which style etc? I hope you ca see from this that you have provided insufficient data for us to easily help you.

Please also tell us which bibliography style you employ.

If you're using natbib then the correct commands are \citet for Author (year) and \citep for (Author, year).  If you're using biblatex the equivalent commands are \textcite and \parencite, respectively.
